# I need to display the post value in drupal

Tags: drupal

$query = $this->database->select('users_field_data', 'u');

```
$query->innerJoin(
  'group_content_field_data',
  'gc',
  "gc.entity_id = u.uid"
);

$query->leftJoin(
  'opigno_learning_path_achievements',
  'a',
  'a.uid = u.uid'
);

echo $status = \Drupal::request()->query->get('status');

    $query->condition('u.status',$status);
```

I have tried with this line after selecting on the dropdown and then click on the submit button but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/class/Request/9.1.x), `\Drupal::request()->query` with get the query parameters, to get the post parameters use `\Drupal::request()->request`.

ie. change.
`\Drupal::request()->query->get('status');`
to
`\Drupal::request()->request->get('status');`